# linux + top command

Tags: linux, command, cpu, process-management

I run the top command on my linux machine

and I see that **vim** command take like 99.5% CPU

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                     
 23320 gsachde   25   0 10720 3500 2860 R 99.5  0.2  30895:11 vim
```

how to verify which script/program is it?

Comment: you can see this post from stackoverflow site:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137304/how-can-i-find-which-vim-plugin-is-guilty-for-overloading-my-cpu

maybe you will find the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press `c` while in top then the command will be expanded to show the full command used to start the process.

You can also take the PID and run:

```
  ps -ef |  grep $PID
```

Or:

```
  cat /proc/$PID/cmdline
```